# Maximo Anywhere Custom app doesn't cache all records that are downloaded to the device

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Environment: Maximo Anywhere 762 / Android 5 or 6

Our dev created an application to run on Android (v5, v6) devices. He has created an custom application based on Work_Execution (standard) app and he just included some new options (like buttons to go forward at the bottom) and a custom filter ("select routes" and "select locations") to attend the Customer needs which allow the end use that will be walking thru their plant to measure the information from the equipment. The application is working but we do have the following situation:
- On Maximo we do have aprox 2.000 records (work orders)
- The end user wants to login to the Anywhere app, select the routes (custom field at Maximo which combines some values) they want to download in order to execute their work (measurement of an equipment) so they go OFFLINE (they don't have WI FI on their way walking thru the plants) and start to filter again for the specific route they want to work (imagine they've selected 3 routes that represents 1st floor, 2nd floor and 3rd floor) that could be individually selected to filter specifically where they are and what they need to measure on that specific floor;

Considers that we are using pageSize=20.

After the login happens, the user click on the menu to select "Download Current List" to ensure all data is downloaded to the device.  It apparently works fine, there's a message that says all records were downloaded successfully. After the user go OFFLINE and try to search for an specific route (for example the last record of that route) they can't find it.

Our impression is that when we do set a pageSize=20 (to improve the response time) all the records are downlodade to the device but only 20 records goes to CACHE.  So that, when we do search/filter for a route that selects a work order that is only on the storage but not on CACHE, it can't be found.

Is that a way to filter/search for the data directly to the storage instead of going to the data in CACHE or force all the data to be in cache and storage?

Thanks,C.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem.

I think migrating to Maximo Anywhere 7.6.2.1 might resolve your issue :

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22007895

IV98824 UNABLE TO SEARCH DATA STORED ON DEVICE BEYOND THE PAGE SIZE (280807)